# Analyze Repeated Measures Data Using PROC GLIMMIX, HAVING CODE PROBLEM

Tags: sas, data-analysis, mixed-models

I am using PROC GLIMMIX to analyze repeated measures data on therapy. The original data included visit2 to visit9, with each visit reporting an index reflecting treatment. I would like to create a mixed model to test the treatment, which has been transformed into 0 and 1 (0 means unimproved, 1 means improved). I considered visit as fixed effects and the observation I studied as a random effect. I want to find out if there is a relationship between treatment (0,1) and the index reported each visit. I've created three models with different combinations of visits. I used PROC MIXED first, but SAS warned me "WARNING: Did not converge." So I used PROC GLIMMIX instead. However, all the models I created are meaningless, and all the outcomes are the same. Is there anything wrong with my code?

The code I'm working with follows this pattern:

```
proc glimmix data=changed_therapy;
    /*visit为访视2-9，observation为唯一编号*/
    class visit observation;
    /*lymph th1 tnf pge2 il6 cell_number survival are the index I want to study*/
    model group=visit lymph th1 tnf pge2 il6 cell_number survival/solution;
    random observation;
    lsmeans visit/e;
run;
```

I have attached the [lsmeans result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZ9gS.png) for reference.

Comment: look at this(https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67848/is-logistic-regression-still-valid-where-there-are-repeated-measurements-and-gen#:~:text=If%20your%20data%20is%20clustered%20or%20repeated%20measures,GEE%20should%20be%20used%20if%20autocorrelation%20is%20strong.) may be some help.